# Shimano 9 speed road hub compatible with XT 11 speed cassette

Tags: shimano, cassette, hub

I am looking to upgrade my drivetrain, essentially moving from road (Ultegra and 105) to XT mountain.  I'd like to avoid replacing my rear wheel if possible though.

I've read conflicting things about whether the hub spacing between road and mountain is compatible.  Can anyone answer definitively?

Comment: How are you changing from a road groupset to a mountain one? Are you replacing drop bars with flat bars? Are you planning to keep parts of the road groupset?

Comment: I'm replacing the cassette, the derailleurs, the crankset and the BB.  I am keeping the brakeset.

Comment: What are you doing with the brake/shifter units? 9 speed shifters ain't gonna work with an 11 speed derailleur and cassette.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I am adding the Shimano 11 speed trigger shifters as well. or maybe even the xshifter setup.

Comment: You are gonna want to check the mountain brake levers have the correct pull ratio for the road brake you presumably have.

Comment: Kudos to a fellow (potential) Xshifter user ;)

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus yes I will be using Shimano short pull levers for this reason.

Comment: @Klaster_1 I'm about to pull the trigger on purchasing the xshifters.  What do you think?

Comment: @dylanmac I left some feedback [here](https://weightweenies.starbike.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=151899#p1431481).

Answer (score 2):

Changing from a 9 speed road to 11 speed mountain raises many, many questions, but answering your specific query:

An 11 speed mountain cassette will fit on a '9 speed' hub. The freehub body width used is the same for mountain 11 speed and below and road 10 speed and below. Road 11 speed cassettes generally requires a slightly wider freehub body. The mountain 11 speed cassette will fit because the larger sprockets can overhang the hub and spokes a little.

Comment: Do I need a spacer?

Comment: @dylanmac to get the cassette on the hub, no. Are you thinking about getting the chainline right?

Comment: No I was more concerned about the cassette sitting on the hub without play.